# Cloud Foundry - Multiple versions of services

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

When I want to deploy multiple versions of same microservice , should I have different endpoints exposed one for each service. For instance if I am exposing CustomerService , should I expose http://host:port/v1/CustomerService , http://host:port/v2/CustomerService etc? Or is there a way to expose a single endpoint and route based on consumer within cloud foundry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [create](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#create-route) and [map](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#map-route) routes that include part of a path, e.g. `v2`.  For instance, you might have two apps, `MyService` and `MyServiceV2`, then you could do:

```
cf create-route SPACE_NAME SOME_APP_DOMAIN --hostname myservice
cf create-route SPACE_NAME SOME_APP_DOMAIN --hostname myservice --path v2
cf map-route MyService SOME_APP_DOMAIN --hostname myservice
cf map-route MyServiceV2 SOME_APP_DOMAIN --hostname myservice --path v2
```

Then, any clients of this microservice can talk to things like `myservice.SOME_APP_DOMAIN/some-resource` or `myservice.SOME_APP_DOMAIN/v2/some-resource`, depending whether these are old clients talking to the old service, or up-to-date clients talking to the newer one.

Comment: Is it a general practice to maintain a single jar and adapters for each version ?